# SQLite in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to read bookname field in database, but it does not work in this class.

How can I use this class?

```
 public Person readPerson(String bookkname) {
    Person person = null;
    String[] columns = new String[]{"id" ,"bookname"};
    String selection = "bookname=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ bookkname};
    String groupBy = null;
    String having = null;
    String orderBy = null;
    String limit = null;

    SQLiteDatabase database = null;
    try {
          database =              sqLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.query("tbl_persons", columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idIndex = 0;
            int payIndex = 1;
            int lastunitIndex = 2;
            int lastlessenIndex = 3;
            int booknameIndex = 4;
            int maxfreeunitIndex = 5;
            long personId = cursor.getLong(idIndex);
            String personpay = cursor.getString(payIndex);
            String personlastunit = cursor.getString(lastunitIndex);
            String personlastlessen = cursor.getString(lastlessenIndex);
            String personbookname = cursor.getString(booknameIndex);
            String personmaxfreeunit = cursor.getString(maxfreeunitIndex);


            person = new Person();
            person.setId(personId);
            person.setpay(personpay);
            person.setlastunit(personlastunit);
            person.setlastlessen(personlastlessen);
            person.setbookname(personbookname);
            person.setmaxfreeunit(personmaxfreeunit);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Database", "Exception:" + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
            database.close();
        }
    }

    return person;
     }
```

I try call readperson class like inner  but cant give data from data base or give to me packagename
Please tell to me way of calling this class ?

```
    PersonDatabaseAdapter databaseAdapteer = new PersonDatabaseAdapter(Main2Activity.this);
    Person persoon = new Person();


    databaseAdapteer = new PersonDatabaseAdapter(this);

          username = databaseAdapteer.readPerson(pass.toString());
```

Comment: you can see code example at http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Please tel to me how can i use method getContact() in your link ?